# Ninject and Custom Membership provider Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, membership-provider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inject repository to custom membership provider with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596441/inject-repository-to-custom-membership-provider-with-ninject)

I have searched much about this topic too much the most close answer was here
[MVC 3 ninject custom membership context disposed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305067/mvc-3-ninject-custom-membership-context-disposed-problem/10390517#10390517)
but I don't have any idea about the details all I have in my application is a domain contains my entities and abstraction for repositories and the implementation everything works fine when I use my Ninject binding like this

```
 public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory{
    readonly IKernel _kernel;


    public NinjectControllerFactory(){
        _kernel=new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }


    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType){
        return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IController) _kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
 void AddBindings(){
        _kernel.Bind<IٍSomeRepository>()
            .To<EFSomeRepository>();
```

but I have no idea how to bind the customer membership provider I have read about this that I have to inject via a poperty but I don't know how, any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry, vtcing as this is too similar to the other question linked

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using Ninject.MVC3 rather than your own controller factory.  Ninject.MVC3 takes care of hooking everything up, you just need to provide your mappings in App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs

Second, don't bother with using Ninject for Membership, unless you're using a custom membership provider.  Even then, it's a lot less of a pain if you don't mix Ninject and Membership.  I would suggest not bothering with it unless you really know what you're doing.

The problem is that Membership is a static class, that creates a static instance of the Membership Provider.  This means it doesn't get destroyed at the end of the request.  There are ways around this, but in general, it's just a lot easier to use Membership as-is than try to make it work with DI.

The question you linked to solves a specific problem, relating to injecting business logic into your custom membership provider.  If you need to do this, then it might be a good choice.  However, I find that most custom membership providers tend to be very simple.